# Escrever testes unitários para a interface ou para a implementação?

Tags: java, testes-de-unidade, junit

Dado o cenário de testes a seguir, onde tenho a interface:

```
public interface UserService {

    /**
     * Registra um usuário no sistema.
     * 
     * @param user
     *            Usuário à ser registrado. Não deve ser {@code null}
     * @return Inteiro maior que zero representando o id do usuário registrado,
     *         ou 0 caso o registro falhe
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             Caso o usuário seja {@code null}
     */
    long register(User user);
}
```

E uma possível implementação que atenda ao contrato do javadoc da interface:

```
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    private UserDao userDao = // Inicializa ou injeta o DAO

    @Override
    public long register(User user) {
        if (user == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Usuário não pode ser null");
        }

        try {
            userDao.insert(user);
            long insertedId = user.getId();
            return insertedId;
        } catch (SomeException e) {
            logger.error("Erro ao registrar o usuário " + user.getUsername(), e);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

No momento em que eu for escrever meus testes unitários para o método `register(User user)`, devo testar a implementação `UserServiceImpl` diretamente? Por exemplo:

```
public class UserServiceImplTest {
    private UserService service;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        service = new UserServiceImpl();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnIdGreaterThanZero() {
        User user = // Inicializa um usuário pronto para inserção
        long insertedId = service.register(user);

        Assert.assertTrue(insertedId > 0);
    }
}
```

Ou testar somente a interface, injetando a implementação através de um ServiceLocator, por exemplo?

```
public class UserServiceTest { // Note que até mudei o nome da classe de testes
    private UserService service;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        service = // Obtém a implementação através de algo parecido com um ServiceLocator
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnIdGreaterThanZero() {
        User user = // Inicializa um usuário pronto para inserção
        long insertedId = service.register(user);

        Assert.assertTrue(insertedId > 0);
    }
}
```

Qual das abordagens devo adotar? Vale ressaltar que novas implementações podem surgir, porém eu faço referência apenas à interface `UserService` em meu código de domínio.

Alguns trechos de código e javadoc foram omitidos para simplificar o código.

Comment: Opção 1 ;) E pelo seu exemplo, o ideal seria mockar o UserDao, assim você não acessa diretamente o banco...

Comment: Teste a implementação. Não faz sentido testar a abstração porque senão você teria um teste plugável, capaz de testar ora uma implementação e ora outra, então se você tiver mais de uma implementação você terá uma delas sem teste ou terá dois testes plugáveis mas cada um ligado a uma única implementação, tornando inútil a sua plugabilidade. Além disso, testando a abstração da maneira como você sugeririu o teste fica dependente do "service locator" que terá suas próprias dependências e quanto mais dependências pior, pois são mais oportunidades de falhar o teste de um código que está funcionando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com relação a que testar, você pode instanciar o objeto com o tipo interface, e ao manipulá-lo utilizar o polimorfismo para chamar a implementação e seu respectivo método. Desta forma todos os objetos serão do tipo `UserService` porém os métodos que tratará será do `UserServiceImpl`. Porém se estiver trabalhando com injeçao de dependência e/ou inversão de controle muito provavelmente terá muito problema para acessar a base via teste, o ideal é utilizar mocks ou simular a inserção.

Comment: Acredito que sua resposta em conjunto aos comentários do Icaro Bombonato e Caffé sanaram minha dúvida. Estou implementando da forma proposta. Obrigado a todos!